# run mvn release with several profiles

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to run maven with several profiles?
I have a java class annotated with @WebService. Depending on the maven profile the targetNamespace will change. If I run the

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

twice, each time with a different profile, I will achieve what I want but the jar versions will not be same regarding the pom version.
So I thought running the release with 2 profiles could do it. Unfortunately when I enter

```
-P profile-1, -P profile-2
```

or

```
-P profile-1,profile-2
```

only one profile gets executed.

Here ary ma profiles:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <properties>
        <target-namespace>sample-1.org</target-namespace>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>${target-namespace}</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>profile-2</id>
    <properties>
        <target-namespace>sample-2.org</target-namespace>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>${target-namespace}</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

I do print out the target-namespace properties to verify that in fact both profiles are running which is not the case.
Thanks

Comment: Check for active profiles: mvn help:active-profiles -Pprofile1,profile2

Comment: checking for active profiles did not help. I have found that for the same plugin to run twice, the execution tag must have a different id for each profile. But doing so yields the same targetNamespace  value for both profiles.

Answer (score 2):

The second command-line (comma-separated profiles) is more correct, but won't quite do what you're trying to do, given your pom.

When you specify multiple profiles, they are *all* active in the same maven process -- it doesn't mean "run each goal with the first profile and then again with the second". So in the command that you are running, maven attempts to run with both profiles active.

Unfortunately, the contents of your profiles are overlapping. Well, the properties are. The `<build>` section is identical in each, which means that it could even be moved outside of the profiles and just declared once.

But the `<properties>` are completely overlapping ... hopefully it's clear that the `target-namespace` property cannot have two different values at once.

---

I wrote an answer below for some ways to address this properties question, which was posed in a very general way. But honestly, for anyone who ever reads this: there might easily be other, better ways to accomplish whatever you're actually trying to do. The OP was clearly attempting to do something more specific and this multiple profile thing was the method they were deciding to try, but they were confused when it wasn't working. A question about how to best solve their *actual specific problem* would probably have been a more productive question. But just in case this *is* a good way to solve *your* problem, here goes.

---

For the purposes of discussion I'm going to ignore the `<build>` contents above, which appear completely nonsensical, and assume that you need separate profiles because you'll *sometimes* want to activate each one independently of the other (maybe when not running `release`).

You can't use two values at once for the same property. You need to have multiple executions occur instead. You have a few different options for this...

1. Multiple commands. No changes needed to your pom, but this requires that your profiles have no real applicability to the actions in `release:prepare`, which you'll only run **once**. If that's *not* the case, this won't work. The first two commands could be combined into one but the third one has to be separate:

   ```bash
   mvn release:prepare 
   mvn release:perform -P profile-1
   mvn release:perform -P profile-2
   ```
2. Multiple `<executions>` of the release plugin itself, with different [`releaseProfiles`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#releaseProfiles) in each one. This is a minor variation on option 1, but might be more appealing depending on your needs:

   ```
       ...
       <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>id-1</id>
           <configuration>
             <releaseProfiles>profile-1</releaseProfiles>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
         <execution>
           <id>id-2</id>
           <configuration>
             <releaseProfiles>profile-2</releaseProfiles>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
   ...
   ```

   Because the release plugin isn't bound to any phase (you run it directly), you'll have to specify both executions separately on the command line, like `mvn release:prepare release:perform@id-1 release:perform@id-2`.
3. Use unique plugin execution `id`s within each profile -- then run `mvn release:prepare release:perform -P profile-1,profile-2` as usual. You'd also have to change the profiles so that they use different property names. e.g.

   ```xml
   ...
   <profile>
     <id>profile-1</id>
     <properties>
       <namespace-1>sample-1.org</namespace-1>
       ...
             <execution>
               <id>antrun-1</id>
               <configuration>
                 <target>
                   <echo>${namespace-1}</echo>
   ...
   <profile>
     <id>profile-2</id>
     <properties>
       <namespace-2>sample-2.org</namespace-2>
       ...
               <id>antrun-2</id>
               <configuration>
                 <target>
                   <echo>${namespace-2}</echo>
   ...
   ```

   ... this assumes that the all the plugin executions are such that they would be fine to run in a round-robin order like this for each phase of the overall build (`clean` phase = antrun 1 then antrun 2; `test` phase = surefire 1 then surefire 2; etc).

Answer (score 0):

Due to [Maven Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) your second option is correct:

> Profiles can be explicitly specified using the -P CLI option.
>
> This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of profile-ids to use. When this option is specified, the profile(s) specified in the option argument will be activated in addition to any profiles which are activated by their activation configuration or the  section in settings.xml.

Hence you need to use next command format:

```
mvn <goals_list> -P profile-1,profile-2
```

If behaviour is incorrect there could be wrong profile configuration in your POM file. Could you please provide its content?

Answer (score 0):

`-P profile-1,profile-2` should be the right form, if it doesn't work it might be due to some conflicts etc. in the profiles themselves.

As an alternative you could try and play with the `<activation>` tags in settings.xml to activate the profiles based on some property, e.g.

```
<activation>    
  <property>
    <name>releaseProfile</name>
  </property>     
</activation>
```

Then set the property in your mvn call: `mvn -DreleaseProfile release:prepare release:perform`. (You might have to pass a value for the property, it's been a while since I used that).